# What future tenses would you use in the following sentences and why?

Tags: future-tense, exam-questions

> You've been studying Spanish for a long time, and I'm sure you _____ (speak) fluently in a few months.

> Whether we like it or not, within a few years biotechnology _____ (transform) every aspect of human life.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add "**will**" for both questions, because they are your prediction, not a plan or something that must happen.

Comment: What do you think of _will be speaking_ in the first sentence?

Comment: Will be able to speak fluently

Answer (score 1):

I would use "will" or "are going to" for the first statement and "will" or "is going to" for the second statement.  The second one could also use the future perfect "will have" or "is going to have" as well.  The second one with either future simple or future perfect basically means the same thing.  The future continuous could be used for both as well:

You've been studying Spanish for a long time, and I'm sure you **will be speaking** fluently in a few months. (future continuous: really no difference here from future simple; future simple is a general statement regarding your fluency; future continuous shows a little more progression into the future.)

Whether we like it or not, within a few years, biotechnology **will be transforming** every aspect of human life. (future continuous: in this instance, the transforming will still be in the middle of happening; it won't have transformed everything.)

You've been studying Spanish for a long time, and I'm sure you **will speak** fluently in a few months. (future simple: general statement/prediction.)

Whether we like it or not, within a few years, biotechnology **will have transformed** every aspect of human life. (future perfect: this means at some point between now and the end of a few years from now, the transformation has completed itself; there will be no need for any future progression of the transformation as the transformation is now done and has been done prior to the few-year mark.)

Comment: "_The second one could also use the future continuous 'will have' or 'is going to have' as well._" Are "will have" and "is going to have" the future continuous?

Comment: I'm sorry. It was a typo at 4:00AM; it should be "future perfect"; not future continuous. I've corrected it above. I make a lot of mistakes when I type these answers after midnight because I'm half-asleep. You could use the future continuous, however, above; it just depends on how you might want to express yourself. The future simple is the best for both though.